# Web page auto refresh at specific minutes after every hour

Tags: javascript

I have several weather servers uploading reports to a central server with separate pages for each station's report showing gauges. The cycle on the uploads is at H+00 and H+30. I need the pages to auto refresh at H+03 and H+33 (24x7x365) to insure the page has current information.

I have tried several suggested JS solutions for auto refreshing pages particularly the Auto Refresh at the top of every hour discussion, but I can't get it quite right. I would appreciate any suggestions or code examples.

Comment: Show us the relevant code you have made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
setInterval(()=>{
    let minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
    if (minutes == 3 || minutes == 33) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}, 60000);
```

Checks every minute if it is currently 3 minutes or 33 minutes past the hour; and if it is reloads the page.

- `setInterval` runs the given code every so many milliseconds. In this case it runs anonymous function every minute (1000 milliseconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour gives us 60000 milliseconds per hour). This is more than enough to refresh the page on time, but not too much to reduce performance (not really a concern; but still nice to think about).
- `new Date().getMinutes()` gets the current date as an object, and then gets how many minutes past the hour it currently is from that object.
- `if (minutes == 3 || minutes == 33)` checks if the minutes past the hour is equal to `3` (e.g. 3 minutes past the hour) or (`||`) `33` (e.g. 33 minutes past the hour).
- If it is either of those values, then `window.location.reload()` will reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach is to use setInterval().
and then just every hour refresh the page.

```
setInterval(function(){
    Location.reload();
},1000*60*60)
```

something like this